# Action Mailer test in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, store, actionmailer

I have some test need to make, but i'm confuse how make it.

The test need is:

1. Check charset when is set to default ISO-2022-JP when environment variable is set true
2. Check charset when is set to UTF-8 but env variable is not set.

Action_Mailer.rb

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default charset: 'ISO-2022-JP' if StoreConfig.set_mail_charset_to_iso2022jp?

  uri = URI(StoreConfig.store_root_url)
  default_url_options[:protocol] = uri.scheme
  default_url_options[:host]     = uri.host
```

StoreConfig.rb

Here's where i set env variable is.

```
@set_mail_charset_to_iso2022jp = (ENV['SET_MAIL_CHARSET_TO_ISO2022JP'] == 'true')
```

Comment: why not `ENV['MAIL_CHARSET'] == 'ISO2022JP'`?

Answer (score 0):

You are able just to check the following condition, to make sure the CP is the same as you require:

```
ENV['MAIL_CHARSET'] == 'ISO2022JP'
```